# TFS2010, is it possible to create a branch retroactively?

Tags: tfs

Been using TFS2010 for just a few months now so relative newbie, and now possibly need to create my first branch, unfortunately I need to create it from an older changeset, is this possible?

Basic scenario is I converted a project from VSS 6.0, with history, and it all came over fine. Project has approx 500 source files.

Before the conversion from VSS we started working on version 4.0 of our project, with no plans to release any more bug fixes to 3.1 so we didn't establish any branches at that time.

So we have made significant changes to about 20 files (which I can identify), but now the client wants to release a 3.11, 3.2, 3.3 etc because not everyone will be ready to go to 4.0 product anytime soon.

I think we want to create a branch, and then use TFS to rollback about 20 files in that branch to an older version, is this possible to do? Create a branch from where we are now, and then rollback some of the files? or does creating a branch cause you to lose history for that branch?

Slightly complicating things is that after we started working on 4.0, besides making the 4.0 specific changes we also have several changes that we made that would need to go into both he 3.1 branch AND stay in the 4.0 branch we are working on now, and furthermore, and more bug fixes we need to put in over the next several months would need to apply to both branches.

Perhaps this is a pretty straight-forward use case for TFS, but just wanted to make sure I don't mess up what is already working perfectly fine.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create a branch from any changeset, and it's very easy from within the Source Control Explorer UI.  Just navigate with Source Control Explorer to the server path you want to branch, select branch, and then you'll be given the option to "Branch From Version".  Just select whatever changeset you want to branch from and your new branch will be created from that instead of the default of the latest version.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you choose to get the appropriate base version with "Get Specific Version" which will summon the sources in the state you need - of your version 3.1.
Then construct a branch to continue work towards 3.1x 
Executing 'Get Latest' on your base branch should result with your sources in version 4.0

Answer (score 1):

I have just done this.

I started my solution with a single branch team project in codeplex :

-**MyPrettyCMS/Database**

-**MyPrettyCMS/Framework**

-**MyPrettyCMS/Layers**

-**MyPrettyCMS/Portals**

-**MyPrettyCMS/Solution**

It's not possible to create a branch of the team project

WARNING ! I tryed to convert Team Project folder to a Branch, it worked but after that, I can't create any branch and I had not enough rights to undo that (I had to ask the Code Plex TFS Administrator to undo for me).

All of this must be done with team explorer and not with solution explorer.

So I created a Team project folder subfolder CurrentRelease like this

-**MyPrettyCMS/Database**

-**MyPrettyCMS/Framework**

-**MyPrettyCMS/Layers**

-**MyPrettyCMS/Portals**

-**MyPrettyCMS/Solution**

-**MyPrettyCMS/CurrentRelease**

Then, for each folder I used the team explorer move command (DON'T MOVE FOLDERS with the Windows explorer even if you have the plug in, because sometimes it fails).

The result is

-**MyPrettyCMS/CurrentRelease/Database**

-**MyPrettyCMS/CurrentRelease/Framework**

-**MyPrettyCMS/CurrentRelease/Layers**

-**MyPrettyCMS/CurrentRelease/Portals**

-**MyPrettyCMS/CurrentRelease/Solution**

At this point you must archive each CurrentRelease subfolder

Now you open windows explorer and you verify each folder and its descendent to see if you forgot some files. If you did, copy it to the new folder, add it to archive with the Add files of Team Explorer. You must archive again.

Right click on MyPrettyCMS/CurrentRelease ans select command create a branch

I used CurrentRelease-To-2-50-001 as Branch name

Then I have

-**MyPrettyCMS/CurrentRelease/Database**

-**MyPrettyCMS/CurrentRelease/Framework**

-**MyPrettyCMS/CurrentRelease/Layers**

-**MyPrettyCMS/CurrentRelease/Portals**

-**MyPrettyCMS/CurrentRelease/Solution**

and

-**MyPrettyCMS/CurrentRelease-To-2-50-001/Database**

-**MyPrettyCMS/CurrentRelease-To-2-50-001/Framework**

-**MyPrettyCMS/CurrentRelease-To-2-50-001/Layers**

-**MyPrettyCMS/CurrentRelease-To-2-50-001/Portals**

-**MyPrettyCMS/CurrentRelease-To-2-50-001/Solution**

I archived the Initial version of the branch.

Now I can work on my next release and make some minor corrections to the current release.